# Scale training set by inverse standard deviation using python

Tags: python, neural-network, training-data, standard-deviation

I am using python and have a training set of data that i need to 'subtract the mean and scale by inverse standard deviation'. Subtracting the mean would just be subtracting the mean from each value in each column i assume, but i have no idea what i am meant to do when it says to 'scale by inverse standard deviation'.

I have googled it but nothing has come up in relation to python or neural networks so i'm not sure how to continue.

Thanks

EDIT: Would this be correct?

```
scaled_train =  (train - train_mean) / train_std_deviation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future these questions are better for CrossValidated.

Let your dataset be `x` then

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(x)
x -= np.mean(x)
x /= x.std()
```

This is called Standardization

This can be achieved with `sklearn` as per the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) for

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
...                     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
...                     [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
>>> X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X_train)
```

## References

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thankyou, i found this but wasn't sure if it was i was meant to do. Cheers.

Comment: Is it possible to scale the test set using the training mean and std as well?

Comment: I think that is a question better suited for CrossValidated ;)

Comment: I asked it there and my question got flagged for off topic :( https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366379/scale-test-set-using-training-mean-and-std-in-python

Comment: It is now, sorry.